# Property component does not exist on type prompto

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

My issue is I don't know how to fix this. I've looked on other questions similar on this site, and none of them helped.
I have this d.ts:

```js
declare module prompto {

    export type PromptoOptions = {
        showPreview: boolean,
        fileName: string,
        outputPath: string,
        components: QOptions[]
    }

    export type QOptions = {
        name: string,
        type: number
    }

    export class Prompto {
        public addComponents(data: Array<QOptions>): void;
        public run(): void;
        public showPreview: boolean;
        public outputPath: string;
        public fileName: string;
        public components: QOptions[];
    }
}
```

this is the class:

```js
import PromptoOptions = prompto.PromptoOptions;
import { run } from "../functions/run";
import QOptions = prompto.QOptions;

export class Prompto extends prompto.Prompto {
    constructor(options: PromptoOptions = {
        showPreview: false,
        outputPath: "./",
        fileName: "output",
        components: []
    }) {
        super();
        this.showPreview = options.showPreview
        this.fileName = options.fileName
        this.outputPath = options.outputPath

        this.components = [];
    }

    addComponents(arr: Array<QOptions>) {
        for (const item of arr) {
            if (!item.name || !item.type) {
                throw new TypeError("Invalid item")
            }
            this.components.push(item)
        }
    }

    run() {
        console.log(this)
        run({ components: this.components })
    }
}
```

and the full error:

```
src/structures/prompto.ts:17:14 - error TS2551: Property 'components' does not exist on type 'Prompto'. Did you mean 'addComponents'?

17         this.components = [];
                ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/structures/prompto.ts:20:5
    20     addComponents(arr: Array<QOptions>) {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'addComponents' is declared here.
```

I just want to fix this. I've been trying to fix this for like 7 hours now. Everywhere I ask no one helps. Just please.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this in the TS playground and I think that *a* fix will be to add the line
`public components: QOptions[];` before the constructor. Could use a different access modifier (`private` or `protected`) if you wanted.

However, I'll also say that I've never seen syntax where you use `import` with `=` and in all honesty I've got no idea what effects that might be having on your code.

For trouble shooting this, personally, I would remove the imports and manually write the types I'm expecting to use in the .ts file to check the class is behaving as I want. Then I'd remove those types and import them to check that the imports are behaving as I want.